# Cannot add foreign keys to mapping tables

Tags: mysql, shopware

i cannot create foreign keys in my mapping table for a m:n-relation.

My Problem:

I work with the newest version of Shopware (Shopware 6 ) on a test machine and I want to develop a plugin which creates a custom entity. the creation proccess of my custom entity (table name: car) and the table proccess with the shopware migration works without problems. At the next step, I have created a mapping table (name: car_product) which handles the m:n-relation with the standard shopware "product"-Table.

At this point I cannot add my foreign keys which pointed to the **product**-table. There is no error during the execution process. The foreign Key to the car-table works fine.

I guess, my schema is not correct or a problem with the product-table is happen..

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car (
    `id_car` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `hsn` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `tsn` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `model` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `year` INT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` DATETIME(3) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_car`),
  UNIQUE (`hsn`, `tsn`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car_product(
  `product_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `product_version_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL ,
  `id_car` binary(16) Not Null ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `product_version_id`, `id_car`),
  INDEX `fk_product_car_idx` (`id_car` ) ,
  INDEX `fk_product_car_product_idx` (`product_id` , `product_version_id`) );



CREATE TABLE product (
id  binary(16) , 
version_id  binary(16),
...
cars binary(16), 
)
```

The id, version_id attributes inside the product table are both the primaray key

SQL-Query to add the foreign Keys :

```sql
 Alter Table `car_product` ADD FOREIGN KEY  (`product_id`,`product_version_id`) REFERENCES  `product` (`id`, `version_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

     Alter Table `car_product` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id_car` ) REFERENCES `car` (`id_car`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Comment: there is no error log ... the mysql server returns : 0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: see the show create table car_product and look if the foreign wasn't add. If there was an error you would get an error.

Comment: Show create tables outputs  " Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint" .. then i have a logic error in my query? Might it be possible, that the references table is not "visibile" during the creation proccess?

Comment: It is hard to guess what you are doing and in what order, you are right you can only create foreign keys to a existing table. so you have to be carefull to have all tables defined before you add the foreign keys, or do it at the end of all create tables

Comment: Thanks for your help! I re-define the table-schema for the car_product table and now it works without problems.probably a typo...